# Optimizing an SBCL Application Program for Speed

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I've just finished and tested the core of a common lisp application and want to optimize it for speed now. It works with SBCL and makes use of CLOS.

Could someone outline the way to optimize my code for speed?

Where will I have to start? Will I just have to provide some global declaration or will I have to blow up my code with type information for each binding? Is there a way to find out which parts of my code could be compiled better with further type information?

The programm makes heavy use of a single 1-dimensional array 0..119 where it shifts CLOS-Instances around.

Thank you you Advance!

Comment: As asked, this is really too broad: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."  If you have a *particular* piece of code that you're trying to optimize, please show it and describe what's the problem with it.  (Although, if the code is already working, it might be a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.)

Comment: As a general note about optimization: regard [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law).  The benefits of optimization depends on how much runtime is taken up by the part of the program that you're optimizing.  Yes, there are some global things you could do, most likely, but it's probably a much better use of your time to run your code in a profiler and find out where you're spending most of your time.  Then optimize that part, not just with things like type declarations, but algorithmic changes, memory allocation changes, etc.

Comment: Im not concerned with algorithmic improvements here. That's another topic. But I see I have to go more into Detail: The Program ist a Chess Program. Most of what such Software does is moving Chess-pieces back and forth. The board is represented as an 1-dim array of  120 CLOS-objects. Looking into the disassembly showed me, that the handling of indices is far from optimal due to lack of type information.  I want to know how to improve the code by adding some. Where do i have to place it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not great to optimize in a vacuum, because there's no limit to the ugliness you can introduce to make things some fraction of a percent faster.

If it's not fast enough, it's helpful to define what success means so you know when to stop.

With that in mind, a good first pass is to run your project under the profiler (sb-sprof) to get an idea of where the time is spent. If it's in generic arithmetic, it can help to judiciously use modular arithmetic in inner loops. If it's in CLOS stuff, it might possibly help to switch to structures for key bits of data. Whatever's the most wasteful will direct where to spend your effort in optimization.

I think it could be helpful if, after profiling, you post a followup question along the lines of "A lot of my program's time is spent in `<foo>`, how do I make it faster?"

Comment: You are  right, Xach.  So I will have to be more specific: Most time is spent with peeking CLOS-Objects from an array and moving them to other positions. This is pure integer arithmetic and adressing. How do I make it faster?

Comment: It can be helpful to define an array index type and declare index variables as of that type. `(deftype array-index () `(mod ,array-dimension-limit)` and `(declare (type array-index i j k))` for example.